# How well is Moore's law (and it's cousins) holding up?

Tags: parallel-computing

I came across a set of articles back from the 2000s that stated Intel was planning a 10Gz CPU by 2011. Obviously, this didn't pan out. But how well are Moore's law and it's cousins holding up in terms of:

- Transistors per \$1000
- Floating point operators per \$1000
- The performance of the world's most powerful supercomputers?
- The computing power available to the average consumer
- Flops per watt of power

And which of these are likely to break down in the next few years?

Comment: That's a lot of questions.  This site is designed for asking one question per post; I see about 5-10 questions here.  Finally, I think you misunderstand Moore's law.  Moore's law only predicts the number of transisters per circuit or performance of a CPU, not all those other quantities you mention.  Have you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%27s_law?

Comment: I'm asking both about Moore's law and there various related laws - that's why I added "and it's cousins". I understand that I'm asking multiple questions, but they're all very tightly related to each other.